# How to import code from outside into gradle build file?

Tags: gradle, groovy

My build files are large and messy, making them difficult to read. like below:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.17"
}

dependencies {
    implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0"
    implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.18.0"
    ...
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0"
    }

    // Generates the java Protobuf-lite code for the Protobufs in this project. See
    // https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation
    // for more information.
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to define the above code into an external file, and then introduce it into the build file, how should I do it?

Comment: does this applies to plugins and dependencies only or to other sections of your gradle file?

Comment: Expect both cases to apply if possible.

Comment: Sounds like you want a convention plugin https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html

Comment: @tim_yates Maybe you're right, I'm a new learner so I can't tell if that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block), as of now it is not possible to move the plugin block to other file than the project’s build script or `settings.gradle` file.

For the other sections, let's say `dependencies` or `protobuf`, then you can move these sections on a separate gradle files and import them by using the following statement:

```
apply from: "${project.rootDir}/your-gradle-file"
```

Of course the path of `your-gradle-file` should be adjusted according to the project's folder structure you decide.

If you want to split the dependencies into multiple gradle file you can do the following:

on your main gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    apply from: "${project.rootDir}/depsGroup1.gradle"
    apply from: "${project.rootDir}/depsGroup2.gradle"
}
```

and within each depsGroup file:

```
dependencies {
   implementation xyz
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed reference code. For example, how does the dependencies code block of external files be introduced into the dependencies code block in app/build.gradle?

Comment: Apply: from should be avoided in favour of a convention plugin